# Is there a Java method that fills a List by calling a function many times?

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, java-8

Is there something like this in the standard library? It fills a `List<T>` by calling `source.get()`:

```
public static <T> List<T> listFromFunc(int size, Supplier<T> source) {
    return IntStream.range(0, size)
            .mapToObj(i -> source.get())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid not, but you can improve readability of your code with this construct

```
Stream.generate(source).limit(size).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Although as [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705447/is-there-a-java-method-that-fills-a-list-by-calling-a-function-many-times/28705651?noredirect=1#comment45733057_28705651) your original version will parallelize much better.

Comment: On the other hand, the example in the question (using IntStream.range) parallelizes _much_ better.

Comment: @BrianGoetz That is very interesting. Can you add some more info (maybe link) about this subject?

Comment: The semantics of the limit() operation is tied to encounter order, and such coupling turn out to be significant constraints on parallelism.  As an example, imagine implementing parallel `findFirst` vs `findAny`; it should be clear that the latter will parallelize much better (since once you find an answer, you don't have to wait for all the earlier elements to finish.)  On the other hand, ranges split perfectly, so the work will distribute cleanly across cores.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thank you. It makes sense now. I am just confused about fact that `IntStream.range` returns `StreamSupport.intStream(new Streams.RangeIntSpliterator(..), false)` where `false` indicates that returned stream will not be parallel (it seems I need to reading some book about Java 8 to fully understand its magic :) ).

Comment: It returns a sequential stream, but you can turn that stream parallel with `IntStream.range(...).parallel()`, and the resulting stream will parallelize extremely well.  Not all pipelines parallelize so well; those containing encounter-order-constrained operations (e.g., limit, findFirst); those whose sources split poorly (e.g., LinkedList, Stream.iterate, those that derive from Iterator), etc.  It's hard to give a quick decoder chart, because parallel performance could be affected by stream source, intermediate ops, and terminal ops, but `limit` is one of the worst offenders.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I missed that `stream` has `parallel()` method. Now it all makes perfect sense. Thank you for your time and explanation.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: but (surprisingly, perhaps), [`Stream.generate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) returns an *unordered* stream, so this solution actually runs in parallel but at the cost of having the `source` `Supplier` possibly produce more items than we will find afterwards in the collected list. So, depending on the `Supplier`, when using it with `parallel`, it might even change the semantics…

Comment: @Holger @BrianGoetz I was about to post the same thing. Yes, this could be a problem if the generator has side-effects, but at best, it likely wastes some work. If you have the choice, running a parallel stream on a definitely-sized source (i.e., `SIZED`) is preferable.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: I’d say, if there was an `INFINITE` characteristics, calling `limit` on an infinite stream could turn it into a `SIZED` stream. Given how often programmers choose solutions like this (apparently, by looking at SO), this could be a big improvement.

Comment: The unorderedness of the source helps a lot (good splittability, much better then Stream.iterate), but then `limit()` comes along and destroys you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another variation:

```
static <T> List<T> listFromFunc(int size, Supplier<T> source) {
    return Collections.nCopies(size, "").stream()
        .map(o -> source.get())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(size)));
}
```

This enables stream to be `SIZED` throughout. `Collections.nCopies().stream()` actually uses `IntStream.range()` internally so it isn't faster or anything, though.

Using `Collectors.toCollection()` enables you to control the concrete type of the list, which `toList()` does not. In the sequential case, this also allows you to pre-size the list, avoiding copying that might occur as elements are added to the list.

(Fair warning: in JDK 8, `toList()` creates an `ArrayList`, but we might change this in JDK 9 to return a list type that's more amenable to appending.)

Comment: Or `Collections.nCopies(size, source).stream().map(Supplier::get)`…

Comment: @Holger Ha! Yes, very interesting variation!